# presentedViewController changes orientation of presenting view controller, breaks layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a ViewController `A` that presents an `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I want to force the video player to landscape, so I use this:

In the AppDelegate, `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow`

```
if let viewController = self.window!.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
            if let playbackController = viewController as? MPMoviePlayerViewController {
                return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft.rawValue) | Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight.rawValue)
            }
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
        }
```

In my video player subclass, I set the supported orientation:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft.rawValue) | Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight.rawValue)
    }
```

When the video player is closed in landscape, however, View Controller `A` is stuck in landscape. How do I prevent View Controller `A` from switching to landscape, and keep it in portrait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

to every view controller that needs it and avoid AppDelegate based orientation support.